# LARAVEL - How to redirect if there's an error

Tags: laravel

I'm making a web application and in the user profile section, I've got a route setup so you go to profile/{id}. When I enter in an IP that doesn't exist on the database, I get this error page: `Trying to get property 'avatar' of non-object (View:`.

I understand why I get the error, but when I get that error instead of showing the page I want it to redirect back to my dashboard page. How do I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can test if in your Controller that handle the show function when you get the object from query, check if is `null` and in true case:

`return redirect('/')->with('error', 'Error string');`

for example:

```
  $user = User::find($id);
  if($user === null){
    return redirect('/')->with('error', 'Error string');
  }
```

Comment: That works. Thanks. How do I display that error in my blade file?

Comment: @if(session()->has('error'))
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                {{ session()->get('error') }}
            </div>
     @endif